# Displaying a fake price in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe's Checkout. 
There is nothing that prevent me (apart my honesty) to display a low price to the customer, and then charge a higher price without his consent.

Did I miss something ? Is that an industry standard ? I believe it's not.
Why the token did not contain the user validated amount ?
Is it only in test mode ?

Thank you.

For exemple, this works (in test mode at least). I can see the high amount in my dashboard.

```
<script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="my_key"
    data-amount="10"
    data-currency="eur">
</script>
```

Then in the server side :

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 10000,
  "currency" => "eur",
  "source" => $_REQUEST['stripeToken'],
));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't miss anything -- it's up to each merchant to correctly display the amount and currency that will be used when actually charging their customers.

Failing to do would very likely result in disputes and chargebacks from your customers, which in turn could lead to your Stripe account being closed.